# Connecting To Oracle Database (on VMware Linux RedHat 5.4) with VS2010

Tags: oracle, vmware

I got win7 home basic and on my VMware i got linux red hat 5.4. I created oracle database on that linux.

I'm asking that : can i connect the that oracle database with VS2010 from my win7 side ?

Is that possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Oracle inside virtualized machine can accept connections. Make sure that networking setting on vm is allowed and that Linux firewall accepts requests for Oracle database (ports are open). I assume that you started database and listener and that you set and use correctly Oracle client side (ODBC,OCI,...)